# Getting the parent value of something inside an object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

This example was inspired by Alex Sexton's blog post [Understanding JavaScript Inheritance](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/):

```
var defaults = {};
defaults.x = 1;

var myObject = Object.create(defaults);
console.log(myObject); // {x:1}
myObject.x = 2;
console.log(myObject); // {x:2, x:1}
console.log(myObject.x); // 2
```

Q: Is there any way to get that value 1 back out of myObject?  I'm thinking of something like:

```
console.log(myObject.parent.x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of all major browsers support `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, with some extra code needed for compatibility for IE8 and older ([check this](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/)). If that is not a problem for you, you could do something like:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject).x
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/eebPT/).

Comment: Thanks netrunner!  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in Chrome and Firefox.

```
>>> myObject.__proto__.x
1
```

Comment: Dude.  Well, since jQuery 2.0 has stopped supporting IE < 9, I suppose I can too!

Comment: Interesting.  The last comment uses new Bar(), which is also new to me.    So many ways to create variables...

Answer (score 1):

You could reference defaults from myObject

```
myObject.parent = defaults;
console.log(myObject.parent.x);// 1
```